# Multivariate time series predictions with RNN - LSTM using Keras

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to build a model in order to perform anomaly detection in multivariate time series. Indeed, I have 21 features which are 21 time series for each time-window. The method lays on RNN - LSTM with Keras, the training is done on 100 time-windows considered as normal data and the objective is to apply the model on a new time window so as to detect whether some time-instances are considererd as abnormal. 
The model predicts the next instance of each feature, so there are 21 outputs of the model.

My "normal" data are shaped like this:
100 time windows with 1650 observations and 21 features.

My way is to build a model to predict the t+1 instance of a vector of 21 features , so I try to shape X and Y giving:

```
train_X.shape = (80, 1649, 21)

train_Y.shape = (80, 1649, 21)
```

train_Y is the t+1 vector of the train_X vector.

I also have a validation set in the training process (to tackle overfitting)

```
test_X.shape = (20, 1649, 21)

test_Y.shape = (20,1649, 21)
```

I found this code on machinelearningmastery.com and tried to deal with it:

```
config = {'sequence_length': 100, 'epochs': 120, 'batch_size': 30, 
'validation_split': 0.2}
layers = {'input': 21, 'hidden1': 60, 'hidden2':60, 'output': 21}

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(output_dim=4, layers['hidden1'], input_shape=(1649, 21), 
return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(config['validation_split']))

model.add(LSTM(units=layers['hidden2'], return_sequences=False) )
model.add(Dropout(config['validation_split']))

model.add(Dense(units=layers['output']))

model.add(Activation("linear"))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Fit network

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=config['epochs'], 
batch_size=config['batch_size'], validation_data=(test_X, test_y), 
verbose=2, shuffle=False)
print("Predicting...")
predicted = model.predict(test_X)
print("Reshaping predicted")
predicted = np.reshape(predicted, (predicted.size,))
```

Do you think I have the right approach? Someone could give me some tips to modify the code or the shaping of the data ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the model run? How is the performance? Have you compared it to any other models or benchmarks?

Comment: I have the same problem @PythAzzMax. Unluckily many of the examples online are wrong, and don't even consider the shape of the data, just through stuff in and at the end they end up predicting the past (this happens if you shape you data incorrectly before putting it in the LSTM). I don't have the solution, but a good answer is needed for the whole community

Answer (score 0):

This code won't run as the data output and model output shapes are inconsistent. Here are a few things to fix and try:

1. Your train_Y shape does not seem to be correct. If you indeed want train_Y to be the t+1 observation of train_X, then train_Y.shape = (80, 1, 21).
2. Why do you use "validation_split" for dropout. It seems poor choice of name for dropout variable as it has nothing to do with validation_split.
3. model.add(Activation("linear")) seems redundant as Dense would already do a linear transformation. More than one linear transformation would be redundant. So maybe replace it with appropriate nonlinearity.
4. As you ultimate goal is to do anomaly detection, you have to come up with a "detection" threshold. So if abs(y_true - y_pred) > threshold, you would call that sample as anomalous.